# Activemq message acknowledgement

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there any way i can acknowledge a message based on the message id only.
My scenario is like this:

1. A web service received message from activemq with ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE.
2. Sends this message to the client.
3. Client sends the acknowledgement after processing it with the message id

Here the requirement is to the webservice should be able to acknowledge the message based on the message id.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you can only call the acknowledge() method on the respective message object to acknowledge that particular message. But keep in mind that calling the acknowledge() method on a message object which is not present in the broker will cause 'Could not correlate
acknowledgment with dispatched message' exception.

Comment: Is it possible to get the next message from queue without `acknowledge` for current message?